# Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: Cannot add task ':client:test' as a task with that name already exists

Tags: node.js, angular, grails, gradle, gradlew

I can't make grails app run with anuglar2. I have created the app with following command:

```
grails create-app <NAME> --profile angular2
```

And when I try to start it up with (./gradlew bootRun --parallel), without any changes, I got following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/*********/client/build.gradle' line: 15

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':client'.
> Cannot add task ':client:test' as a task with that name already exists.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Or more specific:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: Cannot add task ':client:test' as a task with that name already exists.
```

I am currently running:

- Gradle 3.5
- Grails 3.2.8

I have tried updating node.js and npm

Does the error relates to Grails or does relate to setup of node?

Comment: Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: Cannot add task ':client:test' as a task with that name already exists

Comment: Created issue https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10610

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was related to my ~/.gradle folder. I removed the folder and made gradle reinitialize.